# Is it possible to combine with_options and :if for conditional validations?

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to use with_options to group my conditional validations together for admin users.
The second validation for username uniqueness ends up overriding the with_options condition.

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I just forget about with_options and write two separate statements?

```
with_options :if => Proc.new { |user| user.admin? } do |admin|
  admin.validates :email, :presence => true
  admin.validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.category == "customized_username" }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have these two validations, I don't think it's a bad idea to drop the with_options block and just add the conditions directly to each validation:

```
admin.validates :email, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.admin? }
admin.validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.admin? && user.category == "customized_username" }
```

Another thing you may want to consider is Single table inheritance (STI) instead of using a boolean field. I would recommend this if you find yourself doing `user.admin?` all over your application. Using STI, you would have regular users and Admin users and each could contain different logic for each class. The only real change you'd need to make is changing your "admin" field to "type" and making it a string:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class AdminUser < User
  validates :email, :presence => true
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.category == "customized_username" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use two lines, however, it is cleaner to have method than repeat the same logic in Proc.

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :if => :admin?
validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :if => [:admin?, :custom_user?]

def custom_user?
   category == "customized_username"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `unless` instead:

```
with_options :unless => Proc.new { |user| !user.admin? } do |admin|
  admin.validates :email, :presence => true
  admin.validates :username, :uniqueness => true, :if => Proc.new { |user| user.category == "customized_username" }
end
```